# can htaccess prevent a file type being written to a directory?

Tags: .htaccess, file-type

Is it possible to get the htaccess to only allow certain files to be uploaded to a directory?

I have found several posts discussing how to get htaccess to only allow images out, disable php, output scripts in plain text form... but I cannot find if it is or is not possible to get htaccess to prevent files of a certain type from even entering the directory in the first place..

Could anyone possibly help me out on this query?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Apache is a web server, it can generally not control what gets written by a PHP or other script into a directory.

You will need to manage this in the script that you use to upload files.